# Is it illegal to possess a counterfeit national ID card without actually using it?

Tags: france, passport, identity-theft, paperwork

I just came across a lost counterfeit French national ID card on a bus with my name, photo and correct personal details. I am fairly sure about who created or ordered it (without my permission)

My question is: is it illegal to simply possess this card (which is a travel document) as a "souvenir" without ever bringing it with me, let alone using it? To clarify I am **NOT** a French citizen, my real identity card (what I actually use) is Swedish, and I live in Switzerland.

Comment: According to this, I'm inferring that it is not illegal since they are considered "novelty cards": http://www.bbc.co.uk/insideout/extra/series2/teenage-drinking.shtml

Comment: @MichaelC. Interesting, but are those (fake) government-issued docs?